# CSS display:inline wont work?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS. I've been taking a class in college since January. 
Right now on the website I'm trying to make, I'm trying to add social media buttons. 
Here's the HTML.

```
<div id="follow">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="ig.png" height="40" width="40" alt="ig" />
        </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="fb.png" alt="fb" width="40" height="40" />
        </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS.

```
#follow ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

I want the images to display horizontally but they won't. 
They display vertically and not aligned. Here's a picture of it.

[image]

Comment: how you want to display ?

Comment: It works correctly, problem is somewhere else in your CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/8cscLx92/

Comment: its working fine with me as well.

Comment: I found my error. 
I erased my class off the instagram img when I posted it on here, but I never erased the class off of my css. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you expecting like this. Can you elaborate more?

```
  #follow ul li{
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22rnqdhq/